# UIWebView and Canceling Tap Gestures

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a main window xib on an iPad.  The main window has tap gesture recognizers that show/hide a toolbar when the user taps the screen.  There is also a web view in the main window.

How would I go about canceling the gestures if the user clicks a link in the web view?  I don't want the toolbar to toggle if they hit a link.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to check if the view should receive the touch implementing:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
  // test if our control subview is on-screen
  if (self.view.superview != nil) {
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
      // we touched our UIWebView
      return NO; // ignore the touch
    }
  }
  return YES; // handle the touch
}
```

If you want to use the UITapGestureRecognizer you need to subclass the UIWebView as explained here: https://github.com/psychs/iphone-samples/tree/4028ab78af92ab17465338575b78ed80310a613f/WebViewTappingHack

Comment: I want the webview to receive it.  Just not the link.

Comment: Yeah.  The touch.view class is UIWebBrowserView, which I don't seem to be able to access as a class.  I tried doing isDescendantOf with the scrollview that's holding the webview, but that doesn't work either.  The webview is full screen, so if that conditional returns NO, I can't get my toolbar.  I need to catch the links specifically.

Comment: You can use other gesture than UITapGestureRecognizer. If you want the tap you shoul subclass UIWebView as in this example: https://github.com/psychs/iphone-samples/tree/4028ab78af92ab17465338575b78ed80310a613f/WebViewTappingHack

Comment: Sorry, got sidetracked on other issues.  Is there not a way to stop an event from continuing up the UIResponder chain?